# fread does not read character vector

Tags: r, data.table, fread, read.table

I am trying to download a list using R with the following code:

```
name <- paste0("https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/full-index/2016/QTR1/master.idx")
master <- readLines(url(name))
master <- master[grep("SC 13(D|G)", master)]
master <- gsub("#", "", master)
master_table <- fread(textConnection(master), sep = "|")
```

The final line returns an error. I verified that `textConnection` works as expected and I could read from it using `readLines`, but `fread` returns an error. `read.table` runs into the same problem.

```
Error in fread(textConnection(master), sep = "|") :  input= must be a single character string containing a file name, a system command containing at least one space, a URL starting 'http[s]://', 'ftp[s]://' or 'file://', or, the input data itself containing at least one \n or \r
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: A workaround for me is using `read.delim` and then `setDT`, but I still do not get what went wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1)** In the first line we don't need `paste`. In the next line we don't need `url(...)`.  Also we have limited the input to 1000 lines to illustrate the example in less time.  We can omit the `gsub` if we specify `na.strings` in `fread`.  Also collapsing the input to a single string allows elimination of `textConnection` in `fread`.

```
library(data.table)

name <- "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/full-index/2016/QTR1/master.idx"
master <- readLines(name, 1000)
master <- master[grep("SC 13(D|G)", master)]
master <- paste(master, collapse = "\n")
master_table <- fread(master, sep = "|", na.strings = "")
```

**2)** A second approach which may be faster is to download the file first and then `fread` it as shown.

```
name <- "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/full-index/2016/QTR1/master.idx"
download.file(name, "master.txt")
master_table <- fread('findstr "SC 13[DG]" master.txt', sep = "|", na.strings = "")
```

The above is for Windows.  For Linux with bash replace the last line with:

```
master_table <- fread("grep 'SC 13[DG]' master.txt", sep = "|", na.strings = "")
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not quite sure of the broader context, in particular whether you need to use `fread()`, but

```
s <- scan(text=master, sep="|", what=character())
```

works well, and fast (0.1 seconds).

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add the final solution, which was implemented in `fread` https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1423.
Perhaps this also saves others a bit of time.

So the solution becomes simpler:

```
library(data.table)

name <- "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/full-index/2016/QTR1/master.idx"
master <- readLines(name, 1000)
master <- master[grep("SC 13(D|G)", master)]
master <- paste(master, collapse = "\n")
master_table <- fread(text = master, sep = "|")
```